# How to get data from Private ADX using REST API

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I have a Azure Data Explorer (ADX) configured inside VNET. I have also created a Service Principal in Azure AD and given Access as VIEWER to ADX database.

Now my requirement is to access this APIs outside VNET using postman.

I can able to successfully generate TOKEN based on the client ID and Client Secret. But While using this Token to access query API of ADX, I am getting error as

> Error: read ECONNRESET

How can I access this private ADX using REST APIs from outside VNET ?

Answer (score 0):

> To access a private ADX cluster using REST APIs from outside a VNET, you need to have a gateway to forward requests from outside the VNET to the ADX cluster.

- Create a virtual network gateway in Azure to establish a secure connection between your application and the VNET where your ADX cluster resides.

**References taken from**
[virtual network using Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet?tabs=stv2) and [Internal Mode.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-internal-vnet?tabs=stv2)
[image]

Connect your VNET containing the ADX cluster to the VNET gateway created.

- Deploy an Application Gateway or Azure API Management service in the VNET where your ADX cluster resides. These services act as reverse proxies that can handle incoming requests and forward them to the ADX cluster.

[image]

Based on your requirement configure routing rules in the Application Gateway.

Configure authentication with AAD authentication, API keys, or certificates. This allows only authorized clients can access the ADX cluster.

- Configure NSGs to allow incoming traffic on the ports for the REST API requests to reach the Application Gateway or Azure API Management service.

[API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/security-network-private-endpoint-create) to get the **private DNS** for the cluster.

```
armclient GET /subscriptions/<subscriptionIdADX>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupNameADX>/providers/Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/<clusterName>/privateLinkResources?api-version=2022-02-01
```

For more information refer to [MS Doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/private-endpoint)